# Не могу передать число через сокет - C++

Tags: c++, winsock, сокеты, udp

Здраствуйте, есть проблема, суть её в том, что есть Edit1 в него я ввожу некое число, это число умножается на 100, и мне нужно его передать серверу (так как я клиент). Так как я делал по примерам, там передавали используя char массив, но считать из Edit1 число и добавить его в этот char массив не как не получается. *Я новичок в сокетах (использую их впервые), так что буду рад каждому совету*. **Пишу в Borland C++ Builder 6.**

**Проблема: Считать из Edit1 число и передать его серверу.**

```
 //---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "WinSockUDP.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------- -
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void Socket()
 {
    const int iReqWinsockVer = 2;
    WSADATA wsaData;

    if (WSAStartup(iReqWinsockVer,&wsaData)==0)
    {
            Form1->Memo1->Lines->Add("Инициализация библиотеки сокета(Ws2_32.dll) удалась");
            SOCKET s;
            s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

            if (s == INVALID_SOCKET)
                    Form1->Memo1->Lines->Add("При создании сокета возникла ошибка: " + WSAGetLastError());
            else
                    Form1->Memo1->Lines->Add("Создание сокета было успешным!");

            sockaddr_in sockAddr;
            sockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;

            // Клиент:
            if(Form1->RadioButton2->Checked)
            {
                    sockAddr.sin_port = htons(80);
                    sockAddr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_addr("169.254.213.26");

                    Char buf[1019];

                    /* // Пытался сделать таким методом, не вышло 
                    String str = Form1->Edit1->Text;
                    ShowMessage(str);

                    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
                            buf[i] =  str[i];
                    */

                    // Токо что и получается, так это передавать числа ручным вводом
                    buf[0] = '3';

                    while(true)
                    {
                            // Отправляю данные
                            sendto(s, buf, sizeof(buf), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&sockAddr, sizeof(sockAddr));

                            break;
                    }
                    closesocket(s);

                    if (WSACleanup()!=0)
                            Form1->Memo1->Lines->Add("Освобождение ресурсов WinSock не удалось");
                    else
                            Form1->Memo1->Lines->Add("Освобождение ресурсов WinSock завершилось успехом");
            }

            // Сервер:
            else if(Form1->RadioButton1->Checked)
            {
                    sockAddr.sin_port = htons(80);
                    sockAddr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = INADDR_ANY;

                    if (bind(s, (sockaddr*)(&sockAddr), sizeof(sockAddr))!=0)
                            Form1->Memo1->Lines->Add("Связывание адреса с socket’ом не произошло");
                    else
                            Form1->Memo1->Lines->Add("Связывание адреса с socket’ом было успешным!");

                    int iSize;
                    char buf[1019];
                    buf[0] = '0'; // Это для проверки, сменилось ли число 

                    while(true)
                    {
                            sockaddr_in client_addr;
                            int iSize = sizeof(client_addr);

                            // Принимаю данные
                            int ret = recvfrom(s, buf, sizeof(buf), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &iSize);

                            if(ret == 0)
                                    Form1->Memo1->Lines->Add("При отправке данных возникла ошибка");
                            else
                            {
                                    Form1->Memo1->Lines->Add("Данные были доставлены успешно!");
                                    ShowMessage(buf[0]);
                                    break;
                            }
                    }
                    closesocket(s);

                    if (WSACleanup()!=0)
                            Form1->Memo1->Lines->Add("Освобождение ресурсов WinSock не удалось");
                    else
                            Form1->Memo1->Lines->Add("Освобождение ресурсов WinSock завершилось успехом");
            }
    }
    else
            Form1->Memo1->Lines->Add("Инициализация библиотеки сокета(Ws2_32.dll) не удалась");
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TForm1::Edit1KeyDown(TObject *Sender, WORD &Key,
  TShiftState Shift)
 {
    if (Key == 13) // Это обработчик события onKeyDown для эдита, 13 - это Enter
    {
            INT a = Edit1->Text * 100;
            Edit1->Text = a;
    }
 }
 //---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
 {
    Socket();
 }
 //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: пробовали через char* buf; buf = 3; ? на крайний случай не пробовали через Cmd так - char bufarr[32]; scanf("%s", bufarr); > Тут можно вводить.И не понятно что собой представляет  Form1->Edit1->Text ? Ну либо на самый крайний случай вот так - const char* buffer; buffer = str.c_str(); ? А вообще по-моему можно и сразу так -  sendto(s, string.c_str(), sizeof(string),...);

Comment: @gbg sizeof не распространяется на переменные типа String ? ваш комментарий тут не уместен, если человеку нужно передать строку в буфер - решение вполне сносно, и вместо того чтобы осуждать привели бы свой пример, и я не думаю что он бы сильно отличался от моего. Здесь по-моему не конкурс "магистров C++", чем знаю -делюсь, а вы тут клоунаду разводите.

Comment: @LighFusion sizeof() работает не так. Идите читать стандарт и не давайте ошибочных советов, чтобы не занимать время автора вопроса. Чтобы узнать длину строки, нужно использовать string.length().

Comment: Спасибо за ответы, помогло использование **c_str()**. Да извините, что раньше не отписался, просто проблема решилась на следующий день, а за эту тему я забыл. 

**Вот кусок рабочего кода:**

`Char buf[1019];
String str = Form1->Edit1->Text;

for(int i=0; i<str.Length(); i++)
  buf[i] = str.c_str()[i];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо за ответы, помогло использование **c_str()**. Да извините, что раньше не отписался, просто проблема решилась на следующий день, а за эту тему я забыл. Вот кусок рабочего кода:

```
Char buf[1019]; 
String str = Form1->Edit1->Text; 

for(int i=0; i<str.Length(); i++) 
  buf[i] = str.c_str()[i];
```